# Why I am getting the error "cannot determine GraphQL output type"?

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, nestjs

I am trying to create simple appliaction with **Nest.js**, **GraphQL** and **MongoDB**. I wnated to use **TypeORM** and **TypeGraphql** to generate my schema and make a connection with localhost databasebut but i can not run my server with `nest start` becouse I am getting this error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot determine GraphQL output type for getArticles

I have no idea why i am getting this error. My class `ArticleEntity` does't has any not primary types, so there should not be any problem. I tried to remove `() => ID` from `@Field()` decorator of filed `_id` of `ArticleEntity` class but it didn't helped

**ArticleResolver**

```js
@Resolver(() => ArticleEntity)
export class ArticlesResolver {
  constructor(
    private readonly articlesService: ArticlesService) {}

  @Query(() => String)
  async hello(): Promise<string> {
    return 'Hello world';
  }

  @Query(() => [ArticleEntity])
  async getArticles(): Promise<ArticleEntity[]> {
    return await this.articlesService.findAll();
  }

}
```

**ArticleService**

```js
@Injectable()
export class ArticlesService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(ArticleEntity)
    private readonly articleRepository: MongoRepository<ArticleEntity>,
  ) {}

  async findAll(): Promise<ArticleEntity[]> {
    return await this.articleRepository.find();
  }
}
```

**ArticleEntity**

```js
@Entity()
export class ArticleEntity {
  @Field(() => ID)
  @ObjectIdColumn()
  _id: string;

  @Field()
  @Column()
  title: string;

  @Field()
  @Column()
  description: string;
}
```

**ArticleDTO**

```js
@InputType()
export class CreateArticleDTO {
  @Field()
  readonly title: string;

  @Field()
  readonly description: string;
}
```

If you need anything else comment

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`ArticleEntity` should be decorated with the `@ObjectType` decorator as shown in the docs https://typegraphql.com/docs/types-and-fields.html.

```
@Entity()
@ObjectType()
export class ArticleEntity {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Yes i forgot about this decorator, such a small thing, such a big mistake. Thank you mate

Answer (score 19):

For anyone who gets this error and uses enums, you may be missing a call to `registerEnumType`.

Comment: Excellent insight; this is what I was missing!

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I was using the `@ObjectType` decorator, but I was importing from `type-graphql`. I imported from `@nestjs/graphql` instead, and the problem was resolved.

```js
import { ObjectType } from '@nestjs/graphql';
```

See [here](https://github.com/nestjs/docs.nestjs.com/issues/729) for a related discussion on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

I was using MongoDB and I had my `Query` return the schema instead of the model class.

Changing `@Query((returns) => UserSchema)` to `@Query((returns) => User)` fixed the issue for me.

**user.schema.ts**

```js
@ObjectType()
@Schema({ versionKey: `version` })
export class User {
    @Field()
    _id: string

    @Prop({ required: true })
    @Field()
    email: string

    @Prop({ required: true })
    password: string
}

export const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User)
```

**user.resolver.ts**

```js
@Query((returns) => User)
async user(): Promise<UserDocument> {
    const newUser = new this.userModel({
        id: ``,
        email: `test@test.com`,
        password: `abcdefg`,
    })
    return await newUser.save()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Output model class should be decorated with @ObjectType() and then all properties of that class will decorated with @Field().
For any one who is using a custom output model class and NOT an entity(sequelize, typeorm, prisma etc). Because I was using database entity first, everything was working fine till I moved to a more customized output model.

One more case would be someone using class A as output and class B is used within A

```
export class A{
id: number;
name:string;
childProperty: B
. . . . .
}


export class B{
 prop1:string;
 prop2:string;
}
```

In that case class B should also be decorated with @ObjectType and fields (prop1 , prop2 )  should be also be decorated with @Field as well.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error as a result of missing the `@` symbol before `ObjectType`. I Hope this helps anyone else with the same problem.

I had

```
ObjectType()
export class User {
```

Rather than

```
@ObjectType()
export class User {
```